# SQL (LibreOfficeBase) How to perform logic function between two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, libreoffice-base

I'm attempting to filter a table by the comparison between two columns.
For instance, imagine the table Student with column TestPassed and the table Course with the requirement on the test.

Given the following view:

```
id.Course id.Student     Course.TestRequired Student.TestPassed
1         66             True                True
2         66             False               True
...
99        52             True                False
100       32             False               False
```

I would like to filter such a table by performing an NOT(XOR) between condition and student's data (i.e. both true and both false). The results would be:

```
id.Course id.Student        Course.TestRequired Student.TestPassed
1         66                True                True
2         52                False               True
69        32                False               False
```

Is it possible in SQL?
I did something like this. But how to extend it to general logic expression?

```sql
SELECT "IdCourse", "IdStudent", "TestRequired", "TestPassed" ,
       CASE WHEN "TestRequired" = "TestPassed" THEN 'YES'
       ELSE 'NO' 
       END AS Results
FROM "Filter_Partecipant_Course_byTestRequired"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select only the different results, a guess a WHERE clause should do it:

```
Select IdCourse, IdStudent, TestRequired, TestPassed
FROM Filter_Partecipant_Course_byTestRequired
WHERE TestRequired <> TestPassed
```

This way, If one of the value is true, then the other one has to be false to be returned